# Lucene Java Sorting on TextField - Alphabetically

Tags: java, sorting, lucene

I am adding a field to a Document as such:

```
doc.add(new TextField("productName", prod.getProductName(), Field.Store.YES));
```

But when I do a search and try to sort, I do not get things in alphabetical order:

```
Sort sorter = new Sort(); 
SortField sortField = new SortField("productName", Type.STRING, false);
sorter.setSort(sortField);
```

Am I doing something wrong? How do I sort alphabetically?

Comment: this is a bit helpful: http://mygeekjourney.com/index.php/2013/06/05/apache-lucene-how-to-sort-results-by-alphabetical-order/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`SortField`s should not be tokenized.  If you need to have a field tokenized for searching effectively, and also sort on it, you create a separate, untokenized field (`StringField`) on the same content, and sort on that one, like:

```
doc.add(new TextField("productName", prod.getProductName(), Field.Store.YES));
doc.add(new StringField("productNameSort", prod.getProductName(), Field.Store.NO));
```

Comment: Thank you, this helps out a lot. I was hoping that I wouldn't have to create another field to do sorting.